# Android - Creating a centered layout with two side by side left aligned textviews programatically

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout, textview

The title should be pretty self explanatory. I'm trying to create a centered view that looks like a table, and within that view there will be two textviews side by side. I need to do it this way because the font colors will be different for the two sets of text, and the latter one will have an onClick event.

I can created the two views side by side, but left aligned. I can create them within a relative view, but the text becomes center aligned no matter what I do. Here's what I have so far:

```
public void addTableLink(String s, String s1, int g, LinearLayout L, int fsize, int textColor, int backgroundColor, int lpad, int tpad, final String section, final String selection){
       TextView tv = new TextView(this);
       RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(c);
       rl.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
       tv.setText(s);
       tv.setTextSize(fsize);

       TextPaint textPaint = tv.getPaint();
       int boundedWidth = 360;

       StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(s, textPaint, boundedWidth , Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
       int height = layout.getHeight();

       tv.setGravity(g);
       tv.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);

       tv.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(400, height + 5));

       tv.setPadding(lpad, tpad, lpad, 0);
       tv.setTextColor(textColor);

       TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
       tv.setText(s1);
       tv.setTextSize(fsize);

       rl.addView(tv);

       textPaint = tv1.getPaint();

       layout = new StaticLayout(s1, textPaint, boundedWidth , Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
       height = layout.getHeight();

       tv1.setGravity(g);
       tv1.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);

       tv1.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(400, height + 5));

       tv1.setPadding(lpad, tpad, lpad, 0);
       tv1.setTextColor(textColor);

       tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                  
                setMainView(section, selection);
             }
            });


       rl.addView(tv1);
       L.addView(rl);

}
```

Here's what that makes:

[image]

The second line that says "B. Doe" is made with a different method, and is just one single text view (no font color change is needed, nor a onClick event). The third line is made with the above code, and I'd like it to look like that second line.

Comment: Can you draw a mockup of the layout that you want to create?

Comment: @Tim Done, I hope that helps.